# Signal emission after execution of evaluateJavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyside, qtwebkit

I am building a web crawler using QWebPage in Python. My script is browsing through a website by clicking on various links using `evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")`. The resulting contents are then being processed after emitting the signal `loadFinished`.

```
class Crawler( QWebPage ):
...
def __init__(self, url):
    QWebPage.__init__( self )
    self._url = url
...
def crawl( self ):
    signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL )
    self.connect( self, SIGNAL( 'loadFinished(bool)' ), self._finished_loading )
...
def _finished_loading( self, result ):
    doc = self.mainFrame().documentElement()
    link = doc.findFirst("a[id='ANYID']")
    link.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")
```

This is working quite well. However, there is one link where the `loadFinished` signal is not being emitted after executing `evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")`. I have verified that `findFirst` is indeed finding the right element. I have looked at the source code of the website and it seems that the link is executing some JavaScript without loading new data from the server. Is `loadFinished` not emitted in such a case? Or should it always be emitted after executing JavaScript? Is there any other signal I could use to capture the changes to my QWebPage?

Comment: `loadFinished` may not reflect ajax requests, so this may be the problem. You can use `QWebPage::networkAccessManager` getter and `QNetworkAccessManager::finished` signal to detect all requests. Note that the web page may need some time to process received data and update DOM, so changes may not be available immediately. You can also use JS to detect DOM changes on the page, but this doesn't appear to be trivial.